# Is there a drop-in replacement for ActiveRecord to_xml that's faster?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, xml, performance, activerecord

I have a large-ish array (~400 elements) of ActiveRecord objects that I need to convert to XML.  I've used `array.to_xml` for convenience, but it's very slow -- about 20 seconds when the server is busy, and about 5 seconds when idle.

I've just run a few benchmarks while the server was idle, and found that:

- the ActiveRecord query (complete with two-level :include) takes about 0.3s on average.
- converting that result set to XML takes about 4.9s on average.  4.86s of that is User CPU time.

Is there a drop-in replacement for Builder::XmlMarkup that will improve the speed of to_xml?  Or will I have to hand-roll something?

Comment: This question is now out of date. Same basic question for rails 3 here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5891507/does-rti-fastxml-or-anything-like-it-work-with-rails-3-to-speed-up-xml-renderin

Answer (score 1):

Following link claims a 2 - 3x speed increase. It's not a drop in replacement but rather a technique one uses to build a structure that to_xml will traverse faster.. [Faster alternatives to ActiveRecord::Base.to_xml (Rails Performance Series)](http://www.iprog.com/posting/2009/11/faster-alternatives-activerecord-to_xml-rails-ruby)

Answer (score 0):

You might as well want to check out http://github.com/rti/FastXml

This is a simple Rails plug-in which replaces Array#to_xml and ActiveRecord::Base#to_xml. It uses the 'libxml-ruby' gem (which is a native binding to libxml) to generate the documents.