# Does rti/FastXml, or anything like it, work with rails 3 to speed-up xml rendering?

Tags: xml, performance, ruby-on-rails-3, xml-serialization, activemodel

We have a REST api implemented in **rails 3**, which is using the `yajl` back-end for `json`. It is currently generating `json` responses significantly faster than `xml` when serializing more than about 20 rows.

My next thought was that there must be a similar C-library drop-in for rail 3, which would use `libxml` or similar for `to_xml`, just as we're already using `libyajl` for `to_json`.

To date, I've found only the **rti/FastXml** project: https://github.com/rti/FastXml
It claims to be what I want, but hasn't been updated since early 2010, and has no visible forks.

Does anyone know if **FasterXml** works (or not) with **rails 3**?

More importantly, does anyone know any other ways to get rails 3 to do a faster `render :xml => @search_results`?

Many thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Tests of a few rails 3 config options, via `ab`: `XmlMini_LibXML`, `XmlMini_Nokogiri`, `fast_xs`.

The following request returns about 50k of search results in the form of nested ruby hashes, with the data coming from memcached, so that the time differences here are in encoding the results into xml or json.

```
ab -n 100 -c 5 "http://DOMAIN/PATH.(xml|json)"
```

**SUMMARY:**
Adding gem `fast_xs` appears to cut XML time in half, others have no effect.

1. JSON (yajl)

   ```
                 min  mean[+/-sd] median   max
   Connect:        0    1   2.7      0      20
   Processing:   159  453 188.6    387     994
   Waiting:      155  444 188.4    380     992
   Total:        160  454 188.6    387     995
   ```
2. XML (rails 3.0.3 defaults)

   ```
                 min  mean[+/-sd] median   max
   Connect:        0    1   2.6      0      10
   Processing:   377 1256 337.5   1260    2612
   Waiting:      367 1233 335.7   1230    2597
   Total:        378 1258 337.3   1260    2613
   ```
3. XML (XmlMini_LibXML)

   ```
                 min  mean[+/-sd] median   max
   Connect:        0    1   2.3      0      13
   Processing:   479 1217 233.8   1251    1830
   Waiting:      473 1188 235.3   1229    1826
   Total:        479 1218 234.0   1252    1835
   ```
4. XML (XmlMini_Nokogiri)

   ```
                 min  mean[+/-sd] median   max
   Connect:        0    1   1.8      0      10
   Processing:   701 1211 228.1   1259    1654
   Waiting:      695 1197 224.8   1251    1650
   Total:        701 1212 228.4   1261    1655
   ```
5. XML (defaults + fast_xs)

   ```
                 min  mean[+/-sd] median   max
   Connect:        0    1   1.9      0      10
   Processing:   243  656 233.1    702    1288
   Waiting:      238  627 236.7    585    1286
   Total:        250  657 233.3    702    1289
   ```
6. XML (XmlMini_LibXML + fast_xs)

   ```
                 min  mean[+/-sd] median   max
   Connect:        0    1   1.8      0      10
   Processing:   256  685 222.6    704    1138
   Waiting:      234  650 229.5    661    1132
   Total:        257  686 222.7    705    1138
   ```
7. XML (XmlMini_Nokogiri + fast_xs)

   ```
                 min  mean[+/-sd] median   max
   Connect:        0    2   3.9      0      23
   Processing:   210  657 224.7    714    1118
   Waiting:      206  610 229.9    607    1094
   Total:        210  659 225.0    716    1119
   ```
8. JSON (yajl + fast_xs)

   ```
                 min  mean[+/-sd] median   max
   Connect:        0    1   1.8      0      11
   Processing:   153  442 197.1    396    1129
   Waiting:      148  435 196.3    391    1124
   Total:        153  442 197.3    398    1136
   ```